# Globally replace in Postgres JSONB field

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I need to globally replace a particular string that occurs multiple places in a nested JSON structure, thats stored as jsonb in a postgres table.  For example:

```
{
  "location": "tmp/config",
  "alternate_location": {
    "name": "config",
    "location": "tmp/config"
  }
}
```

...should become:

```
{
  "location": "tmp/new_config",
  "alternate_location": {
    "name": "config",
    "location": "tmp/new_config"
  }
}
```

I've tried:

```
UPDATE files SET meta_data = to_json(replace(data::TEXT, 'tmp/config', 'tmp/new_config'));
```

Unfortunately this results in malformed JSON, with triple escaped quotes.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @klin, whoops, I made the example json valid.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use a simple cast to `jsonb` instead of `to_json()`, e.g.:

```
with files(meta_data) as (
values(
'{
  "location": "tmp/config",
  "alternate_location": {
    "name": "config",
    "location": "tmp/config"
  }
}'::jsonb)
)

select replace(meta_data::text, 'tmp/config', 'tmp/new_config')::jsonb
from files;

                                                replace                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"location": "tmp/new_config", "alternate_location": {"name": "config", "location": "tmp/new_config"}}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 18):

Use update:

```
UPDATE files
SET meta_data = replace(data::TEXT, 'tmp/config', 'tmp/new_config')::jsonb;
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.