# Search and replace key's value in nested JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a json column with this format and How to modify element from postgres jsonb by key?

```
{
  "Content": {
    "CustomerInfo": {
    },
    "Identifier": null,
    "Operating": {
      "Identifier": "ABC-8585",
      "TypeIdentifier": "VAL_OP",
      "SaleIdentifier": "01000042"
    },
  },
}
```

How to remove "ABC-" from Identifier key?

Result In:

```
{
  "Content": {
    "CustomerInfo": {
    },
    "Identifier": null,
    "Operating": {
      "Identifier": "8585",
      "TypeIdentifier": "VAL_OP",
      "SaleIdentifier": "01000042"
    },
  },
}
```

Here is the query I apply to update a json value but it does not work.

```
update "tbleName" set "columnName" = replace('Content.Operating.Identifier','ABC-','')::jsonb ? 'Content.Operating.Identifier'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Globally replace in Postgres JSONB field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720767/globally-replace-in-postgres-jsonb-field)

Comment: @user3738870 I need to update the value based on  key, not globally.

Comment: How about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567543/how-to-update-value-in-nested-json-postgres

Comment: @user3738870 it replaces the whole value but I wanted to cut some values like the old value "ABC-8585" and the new value should be like "8585".

Comment: I see, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a combination of `jsonb_set`, regular JSON reading operators, and `replace`:

```sql
UPDATE "tbleName"
set "columnName" = jsonb_set(
  "columnName"::jsonb,
  '{Content,Operating,Identifier}', 
  replace(("columnName"::jsonb -> 'Content' -> 'Operating' -> 'Identifier')::text, 'ABC-', '')::jsonb
);
```

Here you compute the column's new value in the following way:

1. read the value of the desired nested JSON key
2. do the replacement
3. write back the result to the same nested JSON key in the original JSON structure

Comment: When I execute your query, it gives the following ERROR: operator does not exist: text -> unknown
You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Have you replaced "columnName" with the actual name of your column?

Comment: Yes, I have updated

Comment: What if you explicitly cast your column to `jsonb`? Something like `"columnName"::jsonb` before the first `->`?

Comment: update this code "UPDATE "tableName" set "columeName" = jsonb_set("columeName"::jsonb,'{Content,Operating,Identifier}', replace(("columeName"::jsonb -> 'Content' -> 'Operating' -> 'Identifier')::text, 'ABC-', '')::jsonb);"