# How to Update Specific Entities in a Postgres JSON Array

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres 11.12 database with a table called `workflows_emails`
with a json column called `to`.  The `to` column has the following format:

```
[
   {
      "type":"employee",
      "assignment":{
         "..."
      }
   },
   {
      "type":"external",
      "email":"mailbox@foobar.com"
   }
]
```

I would like to update the json array to obfuscate the `email` field in all entities where `type` field is `external`.  The resulting array would look like:

```
[
   {
      "type":"employee",
      "assignment":{
         "..."
      }
   },
   {
      "type":"external",
      "email":"mailbox@foobar.com.SBX"
   }
]
```

Is there a way to do this with a Postgres query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search and replace key's value in nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74444265/search-and-replace-keys-value-in-nested-json)

Comment: @user3738870 It's very close.  Can you show me how to update the query to replace all matching occurrences in a json array?

Comment: Yes, I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `workflows_emails` table has an `id` primary key column, you can update the appropriate JSON objects in the array by running the following update:

```sql
update workflows_emails set "to" = new_to.new_to
from (
    select id,
  json_agg(
    case
      when element ->> 'type' = 'external' then 
             jsonb_set(element, '{email}', to_jsonb(element ->> 'email' || '.SBX'))
      else element
    end
  ) as new_to
from workflows_emails,
     jsonb_array_elements("to") as element
group by id
) new_to
where new_to.id = workflows_emails.id
```

The subquery in `new_to` iterates over the elements in the JSON array and transforms the objects where `type` is `external`. The iteration is done by unpacking the JSON array with `jsonb_array_elements` so that we can evaluate a condition and transformation on the individual elements. After the transformation of the appropriate elements, we recreate the JSON array using `json_agg`. For the transformation, we use `jsonb_set`, which sets the `email` field of the existing JSON object to a new value.

The result of the subquery is then used to update the original table's `"to"` column.

You can see the results on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HWrTGq6s).

Comment: Wow, amazing. Thank you, I learned a lot from reading your solution.  I would upvote more if it were possible :-)